# jinja2 use double quotes

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

I'm using jinja2 with python3. When I use something like

```
data = { {% for row in data_rows %}
    {{ row }},{% endfor %}
}
```

in a jinja2 template file, single quotes will be used for strings in the output file. Like this:

```
data = {
    70002:{'camp': 2, 'num': 0, 'weight': 0, 'type': 1},
}
```

For some reason, I want to use double quotes instead. Like this:

```
data = {
    70002:{"camp": 2, "num": 0, "weight": 0, "type": 1},
}
```

How can I do this? Thanks.

ps. I've tried {{ row | tojson }}. But it is not useful, because I'm generating a python file with some custom-defined structures, which is not acceptable in json, and as a result, the whole row will be translated into a string.